# Replace parts of video with other videos without re-encoding using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I have a video Video1.mkv with audio and video stream. I have 3 other videos V1.mp4, V2.mp4 and V3.mp4 without audio. I would like to keep the audio stream from Video1.mkv and replace the beginning of Video1.mkv with the concatenated V1.mp4+V2.mp4+V3.mp4

Is there a way to do this without re-encoding? Also, Video1 is 23.98fps and the other streams are 24fps. Is that a problem?

For reference I saw this question was asked before - [Replace parts of video with another video with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1094343/replace-parts-of-video-with-another-video-with-ffmpeg)

But the answer was about replacing the video with a black screen.

Comment: This is possible only, if all 4 videos have the same Audio and Video codec - please check this and post the results.

Comment: @EugenRieck I think you forgot to add a link.

Comment: I didn't. If you refer to "this", then it is to be read as: Please check if all 4 videos have the same Audio and Video codecs

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugen Rieck stated - This is possible only, if all 4 videos have the same Audio and Video codec

In my case, the videos were distinct - hence any operation will require re-encoding.